# Как плавно изменить размер svg изображений?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, svg-спрайт

Подскажите можно вообще svg иконку плавно масштабировать через css, чет я думал что да, но оказывается она как то резко меняет размер и не transition игнорирует.

```css
.svg__icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.block:hover .svg__icon {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  fill: #ff0033;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="0" height="0" style="position:absolute">
  <symbol id="icon-fullstar" viewBox="0 0 9.781 9">
    <path data-name="Фигура 26" class="cls-1" d="M2.654 8.87a.635.635 0 0 1-1-.7l.408-2.276A.252.252 0 0 0 2 5.713L.275 4.102a.613.613 0 0 1 .383-1.131l2.384-.332a.269.269 0 0 0 .161-.111L4.269.457a.65.65 0 0 1 1.24 0l1.066 2.071a.272.272 0 0 0 .161.111l2.384.332a.613.613 0 0 1 .383 1.131L7.778 5.713a.252.252 0 0 0-.062.181l.408 2.276a.635.635 0 0 1-1 .7L4.991 7.796a.281.281 0 0 0-.2 0z"></path>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<div class="block">
  <svg class="svg__icon">
    <use xlink:href="#icon-fullstar"></use>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Только решил демку запилить и все заработало, значит это я у себя уже нарукожопил))

Comment: А можно код ваших исследований ?

Comment: Ну так здесь конкретно что нужно вам менять ?

Comment: @RazGalstyan Да уже ничего, оказывается все транзитится как нужно, буду разбираться что у меня не так.

Answer (score 1):

Может так:

```css
i {
  margin: 100px;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

i:hover {
  transform: scale(10);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<i class="material-icons">home</i>
```

Comment: К вопросу не относится, т. к. это не svg, но фича прикольная!

Comment: а, ну да, не svg, ну ладно

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/770084/178988 - а расскажи поподробнее про эту штуку?

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

svg {
  margin: auto;
  transition: .2s;
}

svg:hover {
  transform: scale(5);
}
```

```html
<svg width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"><path d="M12 0l-2.138 2.63-3.068-1.441-.787 3.297-3.389.032.722 3.312-3.039 1.5 2.088 2.671-2.088 2.67 3.039 1.499-.722 3.312 3.389.033.787 3.296 3.068-1.441 2.138 2.63 2.139-2.63 3.068 1.441.786-3.296 3.39-.033-.722-3.312 3.038-1.499-2.087-2.67 2.087-2.671-3.038-1.5.722-3.312-3.39-.032-.786-3.297-3.068 1.441-2.139-2.63zm0 15.5c.69 0 1.25.56 1.25 1.25s-.56 1.25-1.25 1.25-1.25-.56-1.25-1.25.56-1.25 1.25-1.25zm1-1.038v-7.462h-2v7.462h2z"/></svg>
```